# Vuforia 8.1.10 does not recognize IUnityCompiledFacade and IUnityRenderPipeline as namspaces or types

Tags: unity-game-engine, cloud, augmented-reality, vuforia

Running Unity 2019.2.0a14.

Recently updated Vuforia to 8.1.0 and after including any of the Vuforia gamebojects, I instantly get 5 errores from the `Assets/Vuforia/Internal/RuntimeOpenSourceInitializer.cs` regarding `IUnityRenderPipeline` and `IUnityCompiledFacade`

[image]

After updating to 2019.2.0a14 I was instructed to update Vuforia from 8.1.7 to 8.1.10, which I did, however, the updated Vuforia files need to be added manually to each Unity Editor.

[image]

However, I still get errors.

This is what `RuntimeOpenSourceInitializer.cs` looks like

```
/*===============================================================================
Copyright (c) 2019 PTC Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Confidential and Proprietary - Protected under copyright and other laws.
Vuforia is a trademark of PTC Inc., registered in the United States and other 
countries.
===============================================================================*/

using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Vuforia.UnityCompiled
{
    public class RuntimeOpenSourceInitializer
    {
        static IUnityCompiledFacade sFacade;

        [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
        static void OnRuntimeMethodLoad()
        {
          ...
        }

        static void InitializeFacade()
        {
          ...
        }

        class OpenSourceUnityCompiledFacade : IUnityCompiledFacade
        {
            ...
        }

        class UnityRenderPipeline : IUnityRenderPipeline
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There appear to be a lot of people with this problem and Vuforia's developers have not responded. I'm going to say "this is a bug in Vuforia and there is nothing you can do."

Comment: Looks like I have the exact same issue. I got the code from someone on Win10 and they have no problems, but I get this on Mac. It's really frustrating.
PS: Unity 2018.2 with Vuforia 8.0.10.